# Dynamically insert sub id into iframe code

Tags: php, javascript, adsense

How would i take a sub id from a destination url and have it dynamically inserted into an iframe code before the page or iframe is loaded?

I want to add the subid to be able to track conversions from adsense without having a thankyou/goal page since the iframe stays on the same page.

this is the code i have at the end of my destination url

```
&subid=campaignname_{keyword}
```

this is the iframe code where i want the subid to dynamically insert before loading

```
<iframe border="0" frameborder="0" width="680" height="800" src="http://xxxxxxx.com?PublisherSubID=</iframe>
```

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're trying to modify the actual url of your iframe src or if you're trying to modify the content of the iframe?

Comment: just trying to edit the iframe url before it gets loaded, not the content of the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a page http://xxxxxx.com?subid=12345 and you want to take the subid and drop it into the url of your iframe source.

Try this:

```
<iframe border="0" frameborder="0" width="680" height="800" src="<iframe border="0" frameborder="0" width="680" height="800" src="http://xxxxxxx.com?PublisherSubID=<?php echo $_GET['subid']; ?>"></iframe>
```

This will take the subid from the $_GET array of your page and drop it into the source url of your iframe.

This will also include the "campaignname_" text as well.  if you want to strip that out, then instead of `$_GET['subid']` use `str_replace("campaignname_","",$_GET['subid']);`

Comment: so this will grab &subid=campaignname_{keyword} from the incoming url?  something like this http://aaaaa.com?number=2&id=45&subid=campaignname_{keyword}

i want to grab the subid from that url and paste into iframe url

Comment: Ah I understand now.  I updated the code to match what you're asking.